# SAMSUNG Modem In 2017 iMac

Tags: macos, network, imac, modem

I have a 2017 iMac running Bug Sur 11.4. I have no USB network devices attached and am only connected via Wi-Fi. However, under System Preferences > Network, I see a Modem submenu, where I can input a phone number, account name, and password.

[image]

What does this do, as the iMac doesn't have an RJ11 port? I have no use for dial-up but I am curious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a Samsung phone, connected via any external 'dock' structure?

Comment: I have a Samsung phone that is connected via bluetooth but with no cable, let me unpair that and check. ***Update:*** unpairing my Samsung phone did nothing

Comment: It may have been installed along with any Samsung toolkit to support the phone [I haven't had a Samsung in 2 decades, long before Android was invented, so I've no direct experience with them]

Comment: I have DeX and Smart Switch installed, so I guess that could be why.

Comment: My last Samsung, way back, wanted me to install a whole slew of sh… ermm…cr.. er… helpful stuff I had to pick out manually afterwards. I never bought another ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tejustin helped me predict that the DeX app and/or Samsung Smart Switch caused this extra modem to appear.